# How to SceneKit do not on the whole screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

As in a conventional project Single View add Scene Kit View on View controller, size 250x250. I need create Onboarding page.

In project i add Page View Controller and root View Controller and Content View Controller. I think add Scene Kit View on Content View Controller. I have problem assigning class SCNView on Scene Kit. As far as I know it should be to fill the screen, but I need to do it only for animation pictures.

[image]

Thanks for any suggestions! I'm very excited to hear your suggestions.

Comment: You reference both SpriteKit and SceneKit but these are two different things - which one are you trying to use?

Comment: @ Али Beadle  Any of these options is right for me to implement

Comment: You request speak only about SceneKit, so your title was wrong. Edit your question and be more specific next time. See this link to details: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your question is still not clear. Is that image in your question what you have now or what you want? If it is what you have: what is wrong that you want to fix? If it is what you want: what are you getting now? Do you need  2D graphics (SpriteKit) or 3D graphics (SceneKit) because although your text now says SceneKit your image still says SpriteKit.

Comment: @Ali Beadle Sorry for inaccuracy, I need a 2D graphics (SpriteKit) to create animated icons on the pages as shown in the picture. The confusion arose from the fact that I think that can be done through the implementation of SceneKit, but then I understood that it was stupid. Now I need to implement an animated SpriteKit when scrolling to the new page, the main problem now is how to add it to your project on ObjC creating an area SpriteKit not all єkran and in the center the size 200x200

Comment: OK, no problem. It would be helpful to others if you can edit your question to make this clear. Meanwhile I will post an answer that I hope contains the information you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can constrain your SKView just like any other view so that it only fills the part of the display that you need.

For example, if using storyboards:

1. Create a viewController as normal,
2. Drag and drop a new view onto this controller (Xcode 7 does not have a SKView in the object library, so use a normal view).
3. Size this view and add constraints to it to put it where you need it on the display.
4. Select this view and change its 'Custom Class' to be an SKView.
5. Link this new SKView to an outlet in your code.
6. Use this outlet to present your SKScene into the SKView.

Comment: And despite the confusion in the comments... this answer is good regardless of whether you're using SpriteKit (`SKView`) or SceneKit (`SCNView`). Both can be sized and positioned within another view.